# Method .save raises ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I updated *Ruby* and *Rails* version of my project.

Ruby `2.2.3` –> `2.5.1`

Rails `4.1.8` –> `5.1.7`

When I try to register a new user, I get an error:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:41:in `create'
```

This happens both from client side (frontend) and from Rails console.

*registrations_controller.rb:*

```
39: def create
40:   build_resource(sign_up_params)
41:   resource_saved = resource.save
42:
43:   yield resource if block_given?
44:
45:   if resource_saved
46:     if resource.active_for_authentication?
        ...
```

*In Rails console:*

```
user = User.new(email: "qwe@test.com", name: "qwe qwe", password: '123123123')

=> #<User id: nil, email: "qwe32@q.com", created_at: nil...

user.save!

ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):4
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1))
```

*User model:*

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  include InstantSearch
  include PushNotificationToFollowers
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  serialize :site_link, Array
  serialize :followers_ids, Array

  acts_as_token_authenticatable
  acts_as_follower
  acts_as_followable
  acts_as_liker
  acts_as_likeable

  attr_accessor   :site_link_raw

  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable,
         omniauth_providers: [:facebook, :google_oauth2]

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :slug, uniqueness: true
  validates_format_of :slug, with: /\A\d+[a-zA-Z]+\S*\z|\A[^\s\d]\S*\z/i, message: 'minimum one letter, without spaces', on: :update

  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  {some associations}

  before_create :check_slug
  after_create :set_membership
  after_create :send_welcome_email
  after_create :set_settings

  ransacker :id,
            formatter: ->(bool) {
              users_ids = SoundUploader.select(:user_id).where(active:true)

              if bool == 'true'
                users_ids.present? ?  where("users.id IN (#{users_ids.to_sql})").map(&:id) : nil
              else
                where("users.id NOT IN (#{users_ids.to_sql})").map(&:id)
              end

            } do |user|
      user.table[:id]
  end


  def check_slug
    unless self.slug.match(/\A\d+[a-zA-Z]+\S*\z|\A[^\s\d]\S*\z/i)
      new_slug = "project-#{self.slug}"
      user = User.find_by(slug: new_slug)
      new_slug = "#{new_slug}-#{DateTime.current.to_i}" if user
      self.slug = new_slug
    end
  end

  def set_membership
    self.memberships.create
  end

  def send_welcome_email
    UserMailer.welcome_email(self.id).deliver
  end

  def set_settings
    self.create_setting
  end
```

With other models, I don't get this error.

But with *User* model, no matter how I call `save` method, this error always appears.

Comment: Do you override `save` in your model? BTW since Rails 5 all models are children of `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: Check `save!` method source location `user.method(:save!).source_location` or `user.method(:save!).source`

Comment: @mechnicov Thanks. Changing to ApplicationRecord helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Rails 4.x, an Active Record model inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`.
>   In Rails 5.x, all models inherit from `ApplicationRecord`.
>
> `ApplicationRecord` is a new superclass for all app models, analogous to
>   app controllers subclassing `ApplicationController` instead of
>   `ActionController::Base`. This gives apps a single spot to configure
>   app-wide model behavior.
>
> When upgrading from Rails 4.x to Rails 5.x, you need to create an
>   *application_record.rb* file in app/models/ and add the following
>   content:
>
> ```
> class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
>   self.abstract_class = true
> end
> ```
>
> Then make sure that all your models inherit from it.

I created a new *app/models/application_record.rb* file with the following contents:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

And changed *User* model as @mechnicov pointed out.

From:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end
```

To:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
end
```